# VBA to pull data from various sheets with sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook which consist of a main sheet "Monthly collection reeport" and few sheets with dates. I need to pull the data from all sheets (only total column C14-D14) to main sheet "Monthly" (C4-D14 ) one below other first column with sheet names in column B1-B13 respectively.

[image]

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this? I suggest to look into formulas like CELL, INDIRECT and string operators like MID, LEFT etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the final codes will be

`Sub xxxxx()
Dim j As Integer
x = Sheets.Count ' count no of sheets
For j = 4 To x + 2
Range("B" & j) = Worksheets(j - 2).Name ' main sheet must be the first, run code from main sheet
Next
End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

Adjust this to your needs:

```
Sub xxxxx()
Dim j As Integer
x = Sheets.Count ' count no of sheets
For j = 1 To x - 1 
Range("a" & j) = Worksheets(j + 1).Name ' main sheet must be the first, run code from main sheet
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: for j=4 to ... / replace a with b ... etc