# How to pull Data based on Sheet names using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a collection report with master sheet "Monthly collection" and other sheets with all the dates. Want to have a consolidated data on master sheet. I have all sheet names in my master sheet in cells B4 to B25. Based on this sheet names data has to be pulled frm the respective sheets to master sheet.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Dates As Range
For Each Dates In Range("B4:B25")
If ws = Dates Then
```

......................
    End If
    Next

Some changes have to be made, I am not able to solve this. if sheetnames and dates (B4:B25) match then it has to fetch the data from each sheet from C4 to d4 to the main sheet according to the dates in main sheet.
Could some one help?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA to pull data from various sheets with sheet name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010429/vba-to-pull-data-from-various-sheets-with-sheet-name)

Comment: Haven't you asked the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010429/vba-to-pull-data-from-various-sheets-with-sheet-name. You have answered your own question and also accepted it.

Comment: @ nightcrawler23 Thanks for your Quick response, but with a small change in the requirement. I have sheet names and need to pull data from the sheets from particular cells as mentioned.

Comment: And why don't you just store all of the data in **one** sheet and then create a pivot table to show whatever you want (data for a day or a monthly total or whatever else you want)? By storing all of the data on different sheets your are limiting yourself for no apparent reason (and implement VBA where no VBA would be needed).

Comment: Hi Ralph, I am a starter in VBA , limited knowledge to Visual Basic, I cannot change the format of file  which are in shared drive designed by management.  Appreciate if you can help to code this.

Comment: You can use a formula to pull the data. Use INDIRECT(B2 & "!") will reference the sheet name in B2. Depending on the formula you need it would look something like =INDIRECT(B2 & "!C5")

Comment: No that will be temporary solution where I will have to edit formula very often. I am looking for VBA codes which can automate this.   Below are my current codes can someone help for the below.                        Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Dates As Range
    For Each Dates In Range("B4:B25")
    If ws = Dates Then
    
   End If
   Next

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible for you to use the INDIRECT() function to reference the sheets using the names you have provided in column B something like this. =INDIRECT(text(B4,"dd-mmm-yy") & "!C5") should pull the data from cell C5 on the 03-DEC-16 sheet.

the above shows some error in the formula . could you please check on the below.

The values in column B are dates formatted to look like the sheet names. To get it working use text(B4,"dd-mmm-yy"). I've updated above.

[image]